# Navigating to Details page on creation of record in related list

Tags: lightning

We have related list on details page, let say Object B is a related list on Object A. Clicking on "New" (standard button) on related list Object B, show modal pop up, after filling all the values in the fields and clicking on "Save" button is redirecting to newly created record page. Where users raised a concern stating this is not earlier behavior that is after saving the related list record it used to stay on the record details page of Object A.

I have cross checked in my local sandbox and what they have said is true; where as in higher environment users are getting navigated to newly created related list record details page.

I am unable to figure out this weird behavior, as it is same standard button ("New") but functionality is different. Is this issue happening due to some setting which we can alter or any other issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense, I tried in my standard related list in Lightning and it's not redirecting to the newly created record either. Are you sure the "New" button is standard?

Comment: Yes its standard button and not overridden at all.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting, my best guess is that Salesforce have finally moved that redirecting to newly created record from Classic to Lightning. I am guessing that you are using Lightning. Please see this idea for details.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PWl9QAG

I am not aware of a setting controlling this behaviour.

If this redirecting really needs to go I would make a screen flow creating a record.
Call the flow from a button link on the related list using the flows URL and redirect parameter. Please see this article how to do that.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_internal_url_retURL.htm&type=5

Please share if this helps or give more details so that I can improve my answer.